# How can I invert a MelSpectrogram with torchaudio and get an audio waveform?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchaudio

I have a `MelSpectrogram` generated from:

```
eval_seq_specgram = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate=sample_rate, n_fft=256)(eval_audio_data).transpose(1, 2)
```

So `eval_seq_specgram` now has a `size` of `torch.Size([1, 128, 499])`, where 499 is the number of timesteps and 128 is the `n_mels`.

I'm trying to invert it, so I'm trying to use `GriffinLim`, but before doing that, I think I need to invert the `melscale`, so I have:

```
inverse_mel_pred = torchaudio.transforms.InverseMelScale(sample_rate=sample_rate, n_stft=256)(eval_seq_specgram)
```

`inverse_mel_pred` has a `size` of `torch.Size([1, 256, 499])`

Then I'm trying to use `GriffinLim`:

```
pred_audio = torchaudio.transforms.GriffinLim(n_fft=256)(inverse_mel_pred)
```

but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "evaluate_spect.py", line 63, in <module>
    main()
  File "evaluate_spect.py", line 51, in main
    pred_audio = torchaudio.transforms.GriffinLim(n_fft=256)(inverse_mel_pred)
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/transforms.py", line 169, in forward
    return F.griffinlim(specgram, self.window, self.n_fft, self.hop_length, self.win_length, self.power,
  File "/home/shamoon/.local/share/virtualenvs/speech-reconstruction-7HMT9fTW/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchaudio/functional.py", line 179, in griffinlim
    inverse = torch.istft(specgram * angles,
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (256) must match the size of tensor b (129) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to resolve this.

Comment: Just want to clarify that you can *not* perfectly invert it back. But you can estimate it using methods like GriffinLim as people answered. The resulting audio quality might be questionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for history, full code:

```
import torch
import torchaudio
import IPython

waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load("wavs/LJ030-0196.wav", normalize=True)

n_fft = 256

n_stft = int((n_fft//2) + 1)
transofrm = torchaudio.transforms.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate, n_fft=n_fft)
invers_transform = torchaudio.transforms.InverseMelScale(sample_rate=sample_rate, n_stft=n_stft)
grifflim_transform = torchaudio.transforms.GriffinLim(n_fft=n_fft)

mel_specgram = transofrm(waveform)
inverse_waveform = invers_transform(mel_specgram)
pseudo_waveform = grifflim_transform(inverse_waveform)
```

And

```
IPython.display.Audio(waveform.numpy(), rate=sample_rate)
```

```
IPython.display.Audio(pseudo_waveform.numpy(), rate=sample_rate)
```

Comment: I am getting following error: 
_LinAlgError: torch.linalg.lstsq: The least squares solution could not be computed because the input matrix does not have full rank (error code: 1).

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at the Torch Documentation.

The shape of the input to the Griffith reconstruction should be

`(...,freq,frame)`. Here freq is `n_fft/2 + 1` (presumably it omits the negative frequencies).

Therefore, if you did a 256 FFT than the shape of `inverse_mel_pred` should be `[1,129,499]` not `[1,256,499]`. To get this shape you should just omit all the negative frequency bins of each spectrogram in `inverse_mel_pred`. I don't use Torch, but generally the bins are ordered from negative to positive frequencies (and Torch's utilities are just wrappers for other tools so I am fairly sure it does the same). Therefore to get the desired shape:

`inverse_mel_pred = inverse_mel_pred[:,128::,:]`

Then pass it to `GriffinLim` just like you already did.

I might be off by one or so in the line above so make sure the shape is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The input:

`specgram` (Tensor) has the shape `(…, freq, frames)`, where `freq` is `n_fft // 2 + 1`

So if `inverse_mel_pred` has a size of torch.Size([1, 256, 499]), `n_fft` should (256 - 1) * 2 =510

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the documentation and by doing a quick test on colab it seems that:

1. When you create the MelSpectrogram with *n_ftt* = 256, [256/2+1 = 129 bins](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/transforms.html#melspectrogram) are generated
2. At the same time InverseMelScale took as input the parameter called [n_stft](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/transforms.html#inversemelscale) that indicates the number of bins (so in your case should be set to 129)

As a side note, I don't understand why you need the transpose call, since according to the doc and my tests

```
waveform, sample_rate = torchaudio.load('test.wav')
mel_specgram = transforms.MelSpectrogram(sample_rate)(waveform)  # (channel, n_mels, time)
```

already returns a (channel, n_mels, time) tensor
and [InverseMelScale wants](https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/transforms.html#torchaudio.transforms.InverseMelScale.forward) a tensor of shape (…, n_mels, time)